# Definition of conformal time in de Sitter spacetime

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, de-sitter-spacetime

I'm trying to follow the calculations in http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0201158v2 The aim is to rederive the expressions (2.16), (2.17) for the power spectrum in de Sitter spacetime. In order to do so, we start at the equation of motion (2.10). My problem is the transition from physical to conformal time in (2.10). If I use the definition

$$\eta\equiv-H^{-1}e^{-Ht}$$

for the conformal time, it works out fine. However, I don't understand where this definition comes from.

Starting at

$$d\eta\equiv adt$$

with $a(t)=a_0e^{Ht}$

and integrating I arrive at

$$\eta(t)=H^{-1}e^{Ht}$$

which differs from the expression in the paper by the sign in front of $H$. The sign can be also achieved by reversing the integration direction w.r.t. $t$ when integrating $\eta$, but I don't see why one should do that. It would mean that the conformal time is running in the opposite direction to the physical time.

Any hints are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition of conformal time is actually
$$
a\,d\eta = dt\Leftrightarrow d\eta=\frac{dt}{a}
$$
which gives you the correct result.